# Is there a way to move move excel files and have the copied local path automatically update

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a large mail merge document in excel. Its made up of four columns. Column one has main recipient, two has CC, three has the body and four has the attachment local path. It and the the macro I use to send them all work perfectly on my computer.

However my boss needs to send the emails from now on and I haven't found a way to be able to automatically update the local path as I will have to send all the files to his computer and cant spend a lot of time editing the links.
Any help will be greatly apricated.

Comment: Assuming the 'organisation' of the attachment files will be the same (eg they are all in the same folder, or layout of folders will be the same) then can't you just use Find/Replace to update the links? If this won't work or isn't clear, then you might want to add a sample of the data (as text) to your question eg using [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: Thank you, in my blind panic this never even crossed my mind.